# Why $e_{n+1}=\frac{e_n^2}{2+2e_n}$ instead of $e_{n+1}=\sqrt{a}\frac{e_n^2}{2+2e_n}$

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems

I'm reading Sternberg's Dynamical Systems:

He is explaining why the babylonian algorithm works well given below works well:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n \frac{a}{x_n}\right)$$

Here:

> [image]

I don't understand why the recursion formula is $e_{n+1}=\frac{e_n^2}{2+2e_n}$ instead of $e_{n+1}=\sqrt{a}\frac{e_n^2}{2+2e_n}$. Isn't $x_{n+1}$ away from $\sqrt{a}$ by $\sqrt{a}\frac{e_n^2}{2+2e_n}$?

Comment: Because $x_{n+1}=(1+e_{n+1})\sqrt{a}$. Substitute this into the formula for $x_{n+1}$, divide by $\sqrt a$ both sides and subtract $1$ from both sides.

Comment: $e_{n+1}$ is relative error. You are describing absolute error.